# Can't destroy active record in an unless clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If just come about a behaviour in my Rails app which I can't properly explain myself, but still want to properly understand what is happening.

I have an ActiveRecord object with an `has_one` association like this

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :item
end
```

and a `belongs_to` association on the other side, like this

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :list
end
```

(Class names are taken for illustration and are different from my real world app, so please don't argue that a list with only one item does not make much sense).

I now want to delete an existing item, but only after checking that it actually exists.
I first tried to compare the object to `nil`

```
list.item.destroy unless list.item = nil
```

but here I get an error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved:
       Failed to remove the existing associated item. The record failed to save after its foreign key was set to nil.
```

However, when I instead do the nil check on associations

```
list.item.destroy unless list.item.nil?
```

it actually works as expected.

Can anyone explain to me what is the difference between those to calls, and why one works while the other does not?

Comment: You are using an assignment operator = not the equality operator ==. You should just use the .nil?  method on item

Comment: Oh yes, I'm so stupid xD

Comment: ohh the classic case of `=` instead of `==`. Never mind it happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an assignment instead of a comparison, the correct way would be:

```
list.item.destroy unless list.item == nil
```

Altough positive logic is encouraged, so it would be better like:

```
list.item.destroy if list.item.present?
```